# What would happen if a cell is poked by a fine needle?

Tags: homework, lab-techniques, cell-membrane

I had seen this question in an exam:

A living cell has a protoplasm which is water based and demarcated by a lipid bilayer membrane. If a cell is pierced to 1/5th of its diameter with a very sharp needle, after taking the needle out
(a) no effect will be observed.
(b) protoplasm will leak out from the hole made by the needle for a few minutes until the cell heals the wound.
(c) protoplasm will keep on leaking out till the cell is dead
(d) the cell will burst like a balloon.

I understand that the answer is option (a) as the cell membrane will reseal itself after getting pierced.
But my doubt is that if in the question 1/5th was replaced by 1/2 or by any number greater than 1/2, will the answer be different.
Or in other words, I want to know whether the number 1/5 significant in this question.

Comment: This is a homework question. Unless you show that you made an effort to solve the question yourself it is likely to be closed. [Please look here](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/266/homework-policy-for-faq) on how to properly ask homework questions.

Comment: Depends on the diameter and the shape of the needle, and the hydrostatic pressure inside the cell.

Comment: I don't believe the edits satisfy the need for an attempt at an answer, there's no effort or justification, therefore I don't think it should be reopened

Comment: @rg255 Why not? The OP is asking what (to me) appears to be a valid question about the fraction of lost cell membrane that results in cell death.

Comment: Because there is no attempt to work out an answer and is homework

Answer (score 2):

## Generally speaking, there is no effect in microinjections.

This is relevant in the real world example of [**micro-injections**](http://www.nature.com/protocolexchange/protocols/376). A video of a [pronucleus injection can be seen here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-Bfc1GPWpE), or here is [a more thoroughly explained procedure involving cloning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjkyETBbh_g). As you can see in the video the membrane, **almost no effect will be observed** - [molecular dynamic simulations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lm-dAvbl330) show that the membrane can spontaneously reform from fragments in the tens-of-nanoseconds timescale.

## 1/5 refers to  the question "is the needle small enough?"

The question does include the term *"1/5"*, which is a bit unusual. I guess they want you to recall a specific piece of information about the correct ratio size of needle should be. [Here is a video of a microinjection at approximately that ratio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8bAuJllDvk). *However the exit hole is unintentionally filled with the inserted material and cannot close immediately. The cell disappears out of frame before we can confirm the hole is closed.*

## Cell diameters are very variable

Cell sizes vary greatly.

[image: Table describing different cell sizes. Smallest cell volume is sperm cell at 30 micrometers per meter cubed. The largest is an oocyte at 4,000,000 micrometers per meter cubed.]

From using these values, assuming a cell is a sphere an oocyte has a diameter of approximately 196µm, whereas a neutrophil has a diameter of 8µm. It's a bizarre question given this range because usually [micro-needles are between 0.5 and 5 µm diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microinjection) in length, except in the case of oocytes where larger needles are used (according to wikipedia). I don't think this is relevant, and it is just arbitrarily picking a needle size that wouldn't completely maul the cell!